# Erasing element in a vector while iterating using swap-and-pop

Tags: c++, vector

I want to erase certain elements while iterating a vector, but the below code results in a "vector iterator not incrementable" assertion failure.

```
for(auto iter=vec.begin(); iter!=vec.end(); ++iter) 
{     
    if((*iter).isDead())
    {        
        std::swap(*iter, vec.back());//swap with the back       
        vec.pop_back();     //erase the element
    } 
}
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: look for remove_if, what if back isDead?

Comment: I don't follow. What was the expected result? And why?

Comment: @neagoegab, this is a part of code in a game loop. So if back.isDead(), it will be removed in the next frame.

Comment: Ah, I see now. I have added some basic formatting to your question so that it is in any way clear as to what's going on.

Comment: @neagoegab +1 - your suggestion is better than all the answers... aka dont half fix  broken, replace it with one true way :)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: there are cases where "swap and pop" is a massive optimization over `remove_if`, so IMO it's worth knowing how to do it correctly. Arguably such cases are rare in practice, but compare the two for the case where the vector element type is expensive to move/copy and there is exactly one dead element, at `vec[0]`.

Comment: @SteveJessop - you are right... tbh this reminds me of dreaded quicksort worst complexity. :)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: As I said, it doesn't matter if the back is dead since it will be deleted in the next frame. Plus back is guaranteed to be alive.

Comment: WTF, how is this Q too localized, Steve Jessop just explained why is it good to know about it... I guess ppl who close Q are too busy closing Q to read all the comments.

Comment: @kiwon: maybe before the *first* swap the back is guaranteed to be alive, and will be removed later from wherever it ends up in the vector (that is, the position of the first dead element). But once you've done one swap and pop, the new back element is whatever was the second-to-back element before. Is that guaranteed to be alive?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: they've probably closed because code review is now off-topic for this site. There might be a different way to phrase the question "what does it mean to remove elements from an ordered container by 'swap-and-pop', and how can it be implemented in C++?" that they'd leave alone. Remember, the important thing is that the rules be followed, but if all else is equal then it is permitted to act in the way that results in SO containing useful information ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop - how ironic that the Q i posted motivated by your comments is also on the way to be closed : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13818369/is-stability-of-stdremove-and-stdremove-if-design-fail

Comment: Actually I encountered a problem with this. In debug mode only, I sometimes get a "Vectors iterators incompatible" assertion failure. The stack trace leads to this part.

Comment: Absolutely, this question is very important and not "too localized" at all.

Answer (score 10):

You should increment the iterator only if you don't remove any element at that iteration:

```
for(auto iter=vec.begin(); iter!=vec.end();) 
{     
    if((*iter).isDead())
    {        
        std::swap(*iter, vec.back());//swap with the back       
        vec.pop_back();     //erase the element
    } 
    else
        ++iter;
}
```

Or even better, replace the whole loop with `remove_if`:

```
vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
    std::bind(&ValueType::isDead, _1)), vec.end());
```

Comment: but doesn't remove_if bump down every elements, which is more inefficient?

Comment: @kiwon: `remove_if` might be less efficient, yes, because it unnecessarily preserves the original order of the elements that are kept.

Comment: @kiwon: Both are `O(n)`, but the constant may be different.

Comment: I believe `remove_if` is `O(kn)` where k is the number to be removed and n is the length of the vector.

Comment: @Dan: no, it is required, and easily doable, in O(n). See the sample implementation [from here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove).

Comment: @ybungalobill it says, complexity:Exactly std::distance(first, last) applications of the predicate

Comment: It's `O(n)` calls to the predicate and `O(kn)` calls to the move assignment operator of the element type.

Comment: @kiwon: OK, you are right that it is not *required* to do a linear number of *moves*. The problem is that the standard is indeed somewhat vague on this point. Yet it is hard to imagine an implementation that does not do it so... The same way that the complexity of sort is stated in the number of *comparisons*, but practically it means that any sane implementation will not do redundant copies/moves.

Comment: @Dan: it should only need to do at most `n - k` moves in a vaguely sensible implementation. The standard doesn't guarantee that as far as I can see, so if your library implementation was written by a numpty then you could have this and other performance problems on your hands. By comparison, the questioner's approach does `3*k` moves (assuming default `swap`), which might be more than `n - k` or might be less.

Answer (score 7):

You are incrementing past the element you've swapped with the current element; and if that was the last element, then you have just erased it and invalidated your iterator. You only want to increment if you didn't erase, using something like:

```
for(auto iter=vec.begin(); iter!=vec.end();) 
{     
    if((*iter).isDead())
    {        
        std::swap(*iter, vec.back());//swap with the back       
        vec.pop_back();     //erase the element
    } else {
        ++iter;
    }
}
```

Comment: `vec.pop_back()` may invalidate `iter`, no?