# Is stability of std::remove and std::remove_if design fail?

Tags: c++, stl, complexity-theory

Recently (from one SO comment) I learned that `std::remove` and `std:remove_if` are stable. Am I wrong to think this is a terrible design choice since it prevents certain optimizations?

Imagine removing the first and fifth elements of a 1M `std::vector`. Because of stability, we can't implement `remove` with swap. Instead we must shift every remaining element. :(

If we weren't limited by stability we could (for RA and BD iter) practically have 2 iters, one from front, second from behind, and then use swap to bring to-be-removed items to end. I'm sure smart people could maybe do even better. My question is in general, not about specific optimization I'm talking about.

**EDIT:** please note that C++ advertizes the zero overhead principle, and also there are `std::sort` and `std::stable_sort` sort algorithms.

**EDIT2:** 
optimization would be something like the following:

For `remove_if`:

- bad_iter looks from the beginning for those elements for which the predicate returns true.
- good_iter looks from the end for those elements for which the predicate returns false.

when both have found what is expected they swap their elements. Termination is at `good_iter <= bad_iter`.

If it helps, think of it like one iter in quick sort algorithm, but we don't compare them to a special element, but instead we use the above predicate.

**EDIT3:** I played around and tried to find worst case (worst case for `remove_if` - notice how rarely the predicate would be true) and I got this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;
int main()
{  
    vector<string> vsp;
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i =0; i < n; ++i)
    {   string s = "123456";
        s.push_back('a' + (rand() %26));
        vsp.push_back(s);
    }
    auto vsp2 = vsp;
    auto remove_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto it=remove_if(begin(vsp),end(vsp), [](const string& s){ return s < "123456b";});
    vsp.erase(it,vsp.end());
    cout << vsp.size() << endl;
    auto remove_end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout << "erase-remove: " << chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(remove_end-remove_start).count() << " milliseconds\n";

    auto partition_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto it2=partition(begin(vsp2),end(vsp2), [](const string& s){ return s >= "123456b";});
    vsp2.erase(it2,vsp2.end());
    cout << vsp2.size() << endl;
    auto partition_end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout << "partition-remove: " << chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(partition_end-partition_start).count() << " milliseconds\n";
}



C:\STL\MinGW>g++ test_int.cpp -O2 && a.exe
12345678
11870995
erase-remove: 1426 milliseconds
11870995
partition-remove: 658 milliseconds
```

For other usages, partition is bit faster, same or slower. Color me puzzled. :D

Comment: I don't see that as a fail. Software design is all about tradeoffs. If the standard algorithms don't fulfil certain requirements of yours, there's nothing stopping you from rolling out your own.

Comment: "*because of stability we cant implement remove with swap, instead we must shift every remaining element*". What if the vector is sorted, and swapping violates that invariant? Also, if you need such optimization, you can always implement your own remove, as per the requirement of your software and design.

Comment: @Nawaz - see my edit, if you want to reserve "sortednes"  they should have made you use stable_remove_if

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Or you could call your algorithm `unordered_remove()` or similar. I think the algorithm you're proposing is useful enough to include in the standard library, but so is the existing algorithm. The question of which one deserves the "canonical" name `remove()` is political.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I agree, but problem is that stable_sort is named like that... I guess they can argue that "default" version has no prefix so unstable_remove could be added. :)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: your proposal in the second edit already is in the standard, it's called `std::partition`. From the POV of `remove_if`, it unnecessarily retains exactly one copy of each value removed, and is inefficient for that reason. But you could tweak it to move from the good element to the bad one, instead of swapping.

Comment: Actually, you're starting to win me over. `unstable_remove_if` could reasonably be implemented to use iterator tag dispatch, and do that for bidirectional iterators but do a regular `remove_if` for forward iterators.

Comment: Why was this closed? He's not crying *"wah wah, I want my unstable remove from evil standard comittee"* but asking a valid question about the design of the C++ standard library. Even if you don't agree with his reasoning (that's what answers are for) I cannot see why this is not constructive.

Comment: @ChristianRau ppl here often dont folllow logic when it comes to closing Q. They are esp sensitive to is X in std bad design,should std add this...

Comment: @ChristianRau: I think there's a school of thought that says speculating about how the standards committee reached decisions is off-topic, insufficiently objective. There is a more extreme school of thought which says such questions are always inherently unanswerable, which I think is false in general. In both cases though I think the language design question behind it is valid, but we might fail to identify the specific reason(s) the committee considered. "How should I design the interface to do X" is on average about as good a question as "How should I do X" IMO.

Comment: either way I got good A and we are 1 vote from reopening, so I dont worry too much.

Comment: Regarding performance: I would expect the comparison to be a significant cost in your example code anyway, so there's only so much better `partition` possibly can perform than `remove_if`. Timing `std::count_if` on the same data might give you a baseline cost from which to compare them. Alternatively, try something that's more expensive to move than `string`, e.g. `std::array<char, 100>`.

Comment: Here's my code: http://ideone.com/CyhouF. I get 1747ms for erase-remove, 826ms for partition-remove and 811ms for count-erase. So on the face of it, once you discount the cost of the erase and the cost of the comparisons, the partition takes 15ms and remove_if takes 936ms. Which is more difference than I expected. But in my benchmark, `remove_if` will free some memory and `partition` won't, so that's still not the whole story. `count_if` without erase takes 780ms, so using that as the baseline gives a more plausible difference of 46ms vs 967, a factor of 20.

Comment: @SteveJessop I thought of that(fat objects) but I though ppl would accuse me of fixing the benchmark. :) Ill read your code when I catch time, for this kind of things I need to get some free time, sit down and focus.  :)

Comment: @SteveJessop hi, If I understood your measurements, it should be 56 vs 967, right ? But still even if ppl argue that remove_if isnt used "alone" 2x is still a lot.

Comment: Your suggestion makes no sense at all. Most people would expect `remove` to just delete some elements and keep the rest in order, not swap them around.

Comment: @Danra well I guess most of the people expect that push_back doesnt invalidate vector iterators...

Comment: So your argument is that if some things are already counter-intuitive, let's make some more so? :)

Comment: @Danra - no, make them counter-intuitive if there is a perf reason to do so.

Answer (score 13):

I assume you're asking about a hypothetical definition of `stable_remove` to be what `remove` currently is, and `remove` to be implemented however the implementer thinks is best to give the correct values in any order. With an expectation that implementers will be able to improve on just doing exactly the same as `stable_remove`.

In practice, the library can't *easily* do this optimization. It depends on the data, but you don't want to spend too long to work out how many elements will be removed before deciding on how to remove each one. For example you could do an extra pass to count them, but there are plenty of cases where that extra pass is inefficient. Just because an unstable remove is faster than stable for certain cases doesn't necessarily mean that an adaptive algorithm to choose between the two is a good bet.

I think the difference between `remove` and `sort` is that sorting is *known* to be a complicated problem with a lot of different solutions and trade-offs and tweaks. All "simple" sort algorithms are slow *on average*. Most standard algorithms are pretty simple, and `remove` is one of them but `sort` is not. I don't think it makes a lot of sense therefore to define `stable_remove` and `remove` as separate standard functions.

Edit: your edit with my tweak (similar to `std::partition` but no need to keep the values on the right) seems pretty reasonable to me. It requires a bidirectional iterator, but there is precedent in the standard for algorithms that behave differently on different iterator categories, such as `std::distance`. So it would be possible for the standard to define `unstable_remove` that only *requires* a forward iterator, but does your thing if it gets a bidi iterator. The standard probably wouldn't lay out the algorithm, but it could have a phrase like "if the iterator is bidirectional, does at most `min(k, n-k)` moves where `k` is the number of elements removed", which would in effect force it. But note that the standard doesn't currently say how many moves `remove_if` does, so I reckon that pinning this down simply wasn't a priority.

There is of course nothing stopping you from implementing your own `unstable_remove`.

If we accept that the standard didn't need to specify an unstable remove, the question then comes down to whether the function it does define should have been called `stable_remove`, anticipating a future `remove` that behaves differently for bidi iterators, and might behave differently for forward iterators if some clever heuristic for doing an unstable remove ever becomes well enough known to be worth a standard function. I'd say not: it is not a disaster if the names of standard functions aren't completely regular. It could have been pretty disruptive to remove the guarantee of stability from the STL's `remove_if`. Then the question becomes, "why didn't the STL call it `stable_remove_if`", to which I can only answer that in addition to all the points made in all the answers, the STL design process was a sight quicker than the standardization process.

`stable_remove` would also open a can of worms regarding other standard functions that could *in theory* have unstable versions. For a particularly silly example should `copy` be called `stable_copy`, just in case some implementation exists on which its demonstrably faster to reverse the order of elements while copying? Should `copy` be called `copy_forward`, so that the implementation can choose which of `copy_backward` and `copy_forward` is called by `copy` according to which is faster? Part of the committee's job is to draw a line somewhere.

I think realistically the current standard is sensible, and it would be sensible to separately define a `stable_remove` and a `remove_with_some_other_constraints`, but `remove_in_some_unspecified_way` just doesn't give the same opportunity for optimization that `sort_in_some_unspecified_way` does. Introsort was invented in 1997, just as C++ was being standardized, but I don't imagine the research effort around `remove` is quite what it was and is around `sort`. I may be wrong, optimizing `remove` might be the next big thing, and if so then the committee has missed a trick.

Comment: Why would you need an extra pass? I think his proposal, when you have to remove is to actually do something like `swap(*it_to_remove,*(last_it--));`.

Comment: @KillianDS: if you do that unconditionally, then your algorithm is slower than the real `remove` on average. For example when removing half the elements, it does three times as many moves. So you couldn't just implement `remove_if` to do that as a library "optimization", it would be rubbish. I'm considering the case that `stable_remove_if` is what `remove_if` currently is, and `remove_if` is implementer's choice how to optimize. If that's not what the questioner is asking about then I can try again :-)

Comment: Oh, I agree with that of course (it's essentially what I answered myself). I just misunderstood the extra pass wrong.

Comment: ahh, so for sparse remove std::partition is the way to go... :D

Comment: @KillianDS Why did you delete your answer? It makes a good point and explains the missing performance gain much clearer than this one, which treads a much more philosophical path (still a good answer, of course).

Comment: @ChristianRau: it needed some edits and I was just leaving for lunch, so deleted it until I had time to edit.

Comment: interested parties can  see my code in edit3... really weird results... I would expect partition to kick ass on "sparse" removal.

Comment: BTW was thinking about this, and tbh I thought that you know map iterators that are bi still would suffer from this because normal remove_if would preserve order, unstable wouldnt... it turns out that remove_if doesnt work on map... :)

Answer (score 5):

`std::remove` is specified to work with forward iterators.

The approach with working with a pair of iterators, from beginning and from the end, would either increase the requirements for the iterators and thus decrease the utility of the function or violate/worsen asymptotic complexity guarantees.

Comment: It's a good point. How inelegant would it be for `stable_remove` to take a forward iterator and `unstable_remove` to take a bidi iterator? Inelegant enough for the committee to dismiss it on those grounds? I don't think the questioner is saying that the existing `remove` shouldn't be in the standard, just that it shouldn't be called `remove` since that name fails to advertise that you're (in his opinion) paying for stability.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: well, memcpy only works if the iterator type is pointer-to-POD (in C++11 that requirement becomes pointer-to-trivially-copyable). Or if the optimizer can determine that the iterator behaves as though it is, for example `vector::iterator` might be a thin wrapper to a pointer. `deque<shared_ptr<string>>` has random access iterators, but you won't have much luck copying that by `memcpy` for two reasons (`deque` not contiguous and you need to call the assignment operator to increment the refcount).

Comment: @SteveJessop yeah, I once made that exact mistake with deque :D I cant remember what exactly ms uses memcpy for, but I remember it being used somewhere... either way it is not for copy of RA range. I was wrong

Comment: comment at A: it misses the point. somebody mentioned std::distance() - same name, obviously diff implementation for FW it  and RA it.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question >3 years later :)
Yes it was a "fail".

There is a proposal [D0041R0](https://github.com/WG21-SG14/SG14/blob/master/Docs/Proposals/unstable_remove.html) that would add `unstable_remove`.
One could argue that just because there is a proposal to add `std::unstable_remove` that it does not mean that `std::remove` was a mistake, but I disagree. :)

Comment: If you're going to link to a proposal, you should link to the [actual proposal](http://wg21.link/P0041), not an old draft of it. As for whether the default should be the "unstable" form, I think that would be surprising to basically everyone who wants to remove elements from something. The ability to have a higher-performing `remove` is *important*; don't get me wrong. But it's a lot harder to defend the idea that it should be the *default*, when the behavior would be so unexpected.

Comment: @NicolBolas if the default is either inefficient or surprising, there should not be a default. There should be two functions named `stable_remove` and `unstable_remove` so the choice is conscious, not mindless. That doesn't apply to `std::sort`, because the unstable version is more efficient and is not surprising, thus it's the default.