# "vector iterators incompatible" assertion failure in erasing element in a vector while iterating using swap-and-pop

Tags: c++, vector

I'm using swap-and-pop technique from here: [Erasing element in a vector while iterating using swap-and-pop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13804039/erasing-element-in-a-vector-while-iterating-using-swap-and-pop)

The below code results in "vector iterators incompatible" assertion failure.

```
for(auto iter=vec.begin(); iter!=vec.end();)
{
    if((*iter).isAlive())//update the entity if the entity is alive
    {
        (*iter).update();
        ++iter;
    }
    else  //otherwise, get rid of it
    {
        std::swap(*iter, vec.back());
        vec.pop_back();
    }
}
```

However, when I use a std::list instead of a std::vector, it all runs fine.

Why do I get the assertion failure when using a vector?

Comment: On what line this assertion error?

Comment: @Leonid: `for(auto iter=vec.begin(); iter!=vec.end();)`

Comment: This looks like `auto` is generating a wrong type for you. Have you tried spelling out the type instead of using `auto`? What compiler are you using? How is `vec` defined?

Comment: On a side note, `(*iter).` is the same as `iter->`. ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you call `vec.pop_back()` on the last element, `iter` is invalidated because it is pointing to `vec.back()`. The STL documentation says that `vector::pop_back()` invalidates `back()` and `end()`.

One way to fix this is to detect the special case of `size()==1`:

```
for(auto iter=vec.begin(); iter!=vec.end(); )
{
    if((*iter).isAlive())//update the entity if the entity is alive
    {
        (*iter).update();
        ++iter;
    }
    else if(vec.size() > 1) // can swap&pop
    {
        std::swap(*iter, vec.back());
        vec.pop_back();
    }
    else // need to reset iterator
    {
        vec.pop_back();
        iter = vec.begin();
    }
}
```

Assumptions:

- `auto` is inferring the correct type
- the loop invariant `iter!=vec.end()` isn't being cached